Multipath Icons Missing Details When Converting to Font
I had a script (using webfonts-generator npm package) to convert icons into a .ttf font. It worked fine when the structure of the icon was a single path.See sample below:
For example:
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleIconSinglePath">
        <Viewbox
            MinHeight="24"
            MinWidth="24"
            Height="{Binding Height}"
            Width="{Binding Width}" >
            <PathIcon
                Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}"
                Data= "svg path code"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>

However, after converting to multipath, some icons don't show their finer details. For example, I have an icon that has an outer circle and an triange in the center, and when inspecting the font it rendered simply as a black circle. Other icons rendered with filled areas when they should have no fill.
Sample code:
<DataTemplate x:Key="SampleIcon">
    <Viewbox
        MinHeight="24"
        MinWidth="24"
        Height="{Binding Height}"
        Width="{Binding Width}" >
    <Canvas Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}">  
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" Data="svg path code" />
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" Data="svg path code" />  
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" Data="svg path code" />  
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" Data="svg path code" />  
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}" Data="svg path code" />  
  </Canvas>  
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>


How do I support multipath icons in WinUI 3, if possible? How do I handle the fill of these paths?
Tried looking into PathGeometry for properties that could be used to handle this new structure. I tried changing the pathfill-rule of the svg to "nonzero". I consulted this post: Converting an svg with fill-rule="evenodd" to fill-rule="nonzero"

Path can be set using a string that describes Move and draw commands syntax. Try commands generated by more reliable tools, for example https://github.com/Yqnn/svg-path-editor/tree/master. Or could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Traditional fonts only allow monochrome single paths or compound paths: the pathdata contains multiple concatenated paths e.g the letter "i" (stem and dot)  or "o" (outer oval and inner hole). You can edit you svg in an editor like inkscape and merge paths e.g via subtraction, addition etc.  "exclusion" will define all inner shapes as holes - so probably the most suitable operation. You may also try https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nj7k9jx60p1?rtc=1&hl=de-de&gl=de to generate a opentype svg font. Unfortunately support for this format is still a bit spotty at least for desktop app usage

You haven't explained how you converted to a font.

We use Webfont Generator for the font, with a script that generates a scaled svg. The scaled svg is then used to generate the font. I also tried @vusion/webfonts-generator.

The actual problem is that when the svg is converted to a font, the fill-rule and  clip-rule are changed from evenodd to nonzero.

Fonts don't support fill-rules. you need to change path directions manually/or via script
